# Replace of cron job/cron tabs

Tags: javascript, php, windows, cron

I want to know that there is any way to create an script on windows machine in `PHP` that should run after an interval, let's say every after 15 minutes.

Currently I'm doing it using javaScript, but this is not an efficient way to do that as the browser tab have to be opened always (if user close it by mistake--Script will no longer execute).

So I want to know is there any method to call the script and continue to call it and it should continue to execute even the tab or browser is closed.
One possible technique is to set an infinite loop (but this is not a good approach).

So any help is appreciated.

**Note**: If you don't like it so leave it but please don't give it negative, as my account will be blocked

Comment: Seems more appropriate for serverfault.com. Or google "Windows scheduled tasks"

Comment: @Barmar what about to use loop and set it `sleep(900)` after every iteration.

Comment: I suppose that will work, then you just need to set it up to automatically restart if the server reboots.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking about that too, but if the server keep on crashing then(`wamp on windows`) it crashes very often in loops having too many iterations, and what about `resources`, is it feasible to set loop?

Comment: if your script runs in a loop like that, it should make sure to free resources that it uses, it can't be lazy like most web pages, which depend on all resources being freed when they end.

Comment: I guess script will free the resources when it finish, but in this case it is not completing its execution,then how it'll free resources?

Comment: It depends on the resources. E.g. if it uses `mysql`, it should call `mysql_close()`.

Comment: If it reads a large file into a string variable, it can use `unset $variable` to free it.

Answer (score 1):

The one I am aware of is AlwaysUp... http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/

this is a paid software with a free trial... there could be similar alternatives